# Non EU citizen living in the uk

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens

I have been in the Uk on different visas for nearly 12 years now and have been married to an EU citizen for 4 and a half. Am i now allowed to apply for a permanent visa? if so what do i need ?

Thank you in advance for the help, Legal fees are ridiculously expensive :)

Answer (score 2):

If you meet these requirements, you are covered by the Immigration (EEA) Regulations and the freedom-of-movement directive that they implement:

- you live with your spouse in the UK
- your spouse is not a citizen of the UK
- your spouse is working (including self employment), studying full time, or self-sufficient

(There are some other qualifying circumstances involving people who require personal care.)

If this is the case, all of the following are also true:

- You do not require a visa or other permit to remain in the UK
- You are eligible, but not required, to apply for a [residence card of a family member of a union citizen](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card) as evidence of your right of residence in the UK (the card will lose its usefulness after the UK leaves the EU, after the end of the planned transition period)
- when the [settled status](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families) scheme opens, you will be eligible to apply for either settled status or pre-settled status, allowing you to remain in the UK indefinitely.

> Legal fees are ridiculously expensive :)

The application fee for the residence card and for the settled status scheme is £65.  You probably won't need a residence card.  The total cost of this route is therefore at least a thousand pounds lower than the ILR route.

Answer (score 1):

If you meet the residency requirements, you can apply for [ILR](https://www.gov.uk/long-residence) on your own merit having lived 10 consecutive years legally in the UK.